# Prove that $M \cap \mathbb{N} \neq\emptyset$, where $M = \{ x-qd \mid q \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

I need to prove that $M \cap \mathbb{N} \neq\emptyset$, where $M = \left \{ x-qd \mid q \in \mathbb{Z} \right \}$, and $x,d \in \mathbb{Z}$, $ d > 0$

My attempt: Choose $x \geq 0$ then for all $qd \leq x$ we have that $(x - qd) \in \mathbb{N}$, and thus $M \cap \mathbb{N} \neq\emptyset$.

But I feel like this is not right, can anyone explain how to prove it?

Comment: This is not clear.  In the definition of $M$, what is fixed?  Or does every triple $(x,q,d)$ give rise to an element of $M$?  If so then taking $(x,q,d)=(1,0,1)$ gives an element of $M\cap \mathbb N$.

Comment: It does look like $M$ is a set depending on $x$ and $d$, so they are not free variables.  So, you cannot just choose $x$.  On the other hand, $q$ is a free variable.  What about choosing $q:=-|x|-1$?

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: $x$ and $d$ are fixed.  $d > 0$.  It is $q$ that can be variable.  So prove it is possible for $qd < x$  (i.e. that there exist an integer $q < \frac xd$).  And then, yes, $x - qd \in M$ and $x - qd \in \mathbb N$.  And you are done.

Comment: $x$ and $d$ can not be chosen but $q$ *can*.  Otherwise your reasoning is good.  But when you say "for all $qd \le x$" you *do* have to show that some $qd \le x$ actually exist at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, it appears that $x$ cannot be *chosen*. The statement is nonetheless true, for the following reason: let $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $d \in \mathbb{N}$. If $x > 0$ then $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x = x-0d \in M\cap \mathbb{N}$. If $x < 0$, we can take $q = 2x$ and so

$$
x - 2xd = x(1-2d) > 0
$$

because $x < 0$ and $1-2d < 0$. Thus, $x-2xd \in M \cap \mathbb{N}$. The remaining case is $x = 0$, for which you can take $q = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

To brush away all the obfuscation:

For fixed $x,d\in \mathbb Z; d> 0$ then for any $q \in \mathbb Z$ then $x - qd \in \mathbb Z$.  You are simply asked to prove that for some values of $q$ than $x - qd$ might be positive.

$x - qd > 0 \iff x > qd \iff \frac xd > q$.

So that that's it.  For any integer $q < \frac xd$ then $x - qd\in M$ and $x - qd \in \mathbb Z$ and $x - qd > 0$ so $x-qd \in \mathbb N$ so $x-qd \in M \cap \mathbb N$ so $M\cap \mathbb N$ is not empty.

..... or .....

let $m = x - \lfloor \frac xd \rfloor d$ then $m > 0$ and $m \in \mathbb Z$ so $m \in \mathbb N$ and $m \in M$.  So $m \in M \cap \mathbb N$ and  $M \cap \mathbb N\ne \emptyset$.